# Spring boot jpa + cassandra + mysql

Tags: mysql, cassandra, spring-boot

I want to use both cassandra and MySQL in my project (Some objects will be saved in cassandra, some other will be save in MySQL. My issue is how to config it.

Currently, my configuration is

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = { "com.example.cassandra.repository" })
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:cassandra.properties" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.example.mysql.repository" })
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.example.mysql.model")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Application extends AbstractCqlTemplateConfiguration {}
```

But, I can not @Autowired an Repository from MySQL dialect, as well as can not @Autowired SessionFactory. Please help me to config them.

Answer (score 0):

Could you show more error log. But i think you should separate them into two different sub-projects. It can make your code more clean and maintainable.